# JSQMessageViewController How to get message bubble rect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using JSQMessagesViewController for my chat app.
I would like to get rect of each `messageBubbleImageView`.

I understand the cells including `messageBubbleImageView` are created in `JSQMessagesViewController.m` and I can see the rect of `cell.textView.frame` and `cell.mediaView.frame` by using NSLog, but I do not know how to get the rect in `@interface ViewController : JSQMessagesViewController` from `JSQMessagesViewController.m`.

I would highly appreciate if someone can help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

**JSQMessagesViewController** has a **collectionView** property.  **UICollectionView** has a property called **visibleCells** https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618056-visiblecells

Only the visible cells are going to have frames, because the layout is performed lazily (this actually sort of changes in iOS 10 as a performance optimization but I don't think you need to worry about it, but if you do watch this: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/219/)

```
    for cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
        print (cell.frame)
    }
```

Comment: In JSQMessagesViewController.m I can get frames within this process "- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath". However, I do not know how to get frames in ViewController.m which I created and where actual chat view is displayed. How can I get cell information in this ViewController?

Comment: Oh, now I got what you said. I can get the frames. Thanks!